# how do I filter individual characters with regex

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I need a regex that allows me to use all characters except `|`. I need this for a text input in a flutter app. Here I want to make sure that this character is not present in the text. The widget in which I use this looks like this.

```
                     TextField(
                        inputFormatters: [
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                             RegExp(>>regex here<<)),
                        ],
                        maxLength: 20,
                        controller: titleEditingController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Title',
                          label: Text("Title"),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: Do you need to remove it from the input string? Or trigger an error if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [deny](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter/FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny.html) method, and the following Regex - `[|]`.

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'[|]'))
```

Comment: I think that would be the same as .deny('|').   No need to make it a regex.